# Error getting PAM / Linux integrated with Active Directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to add a Linux server to a network which is controlled by AD.  The aim is that users of the server will be able to authenticate against the AD domain.  I have Kerberos working, but NSS / PAM are more problematic.  I'm trying to debug with a simple command such as the following, please see the error.  Can anyone assist me to debug?

```
root@antonyg04:~# ldapsearch -H ldap://raadc04.corp.MUNGED.com/ -x -D
"cn=MUNGED,ou=Users,dc=corp,dc=MUNGED,dc=com" -W uid=MUNGED
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext 
error, data 525, vece
```

I have had to munge some details, but I can tell you that cn=MUNGED is my username for logging into the AD domain, and the password that I typed was the password for said domain.  I don't know why it says "Invalid credentials", and the rest of the error is so cryptic, I have no idea.

Is my approach somehow flawed?  Is my DN obviously wrong?  How can I confirm the correct DN?  There was a tool online but I can't find it.

NB I have no access to the AD Server for administration or configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some good help on IRC, and I can now bind with:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://raadc04.corp.MUNGED.com/ -x -D USERNAME_MUNGED@DOMAIN_MUNGED.com
-W sAMAccountName=MUNGED
```

So I changed the -D parameter, and the lookup from uid to sAMAccountName.

Answer (score 0):

I have documented this process here, it was a while ago but I have some positive f/b and this did work v well with recent Fedora.

Your problem here is that your username and password for using the ldap tools needs to be a bind user for the AD and your credentials are insufficient.

However, I suspect that the key thing you need is to be able to get keys and bind, which you have to have an admin account for. i.e. You need a friend in admin.

There are some simpler ldap auth models but your AD has to agree to talk to them.

http://educationukblog.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I read the link but I'm not sure how much is relevant to my use case, as you don't appear to use libnss-ldap.  I do agree that the bind user is the problem.  Is it the case that I can't just bind as my "normal" user?  And if not, what are the characteristics of a bind user i.e. what should I ask admin for?  It's a big company, and it might be hard to find a real expert - I might have to spoon-feed them a little.